# AspNet Core WebAPI FromBody failing to parse JSon Object

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am having a issue where an IActionResult method inside my controller is failing to parse a serialised JSon Object that has HTML formatting inside a property.

The Json Object basically is a email message passed to a API to be put into a queue.

For example:

```
{
   "Id": 1,
   "Name": "Joe Bloggs",
   "Description": "Hi Adam,\r\nThis is a test email\r\n\r\n",
   "Date": "2020-05-05T13:10:31.1619652+01:00",        
}
```

If it is a simple message as above it goes through fine. However, if the message contains rich HTML formatting then it fails with `500 Internal Server`.

I have tried the following two points but fail to get a solution:

1. Usage of NewtonsoftJson Core Nuget package and `services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();`
2. Extract the Json from the `Request.Body` and I get presented by `Synchronous operations are disallowed` so enable AllowSynchronousIO = true and still no go :(

I am not really sure what else can solve my issue? Any suggestions?

Here is the IActionResult method in the controller

```
public IActionResult HandleEmailMessage(int Id, [FromBody] customClass)
{
    var addEmailMessage = _service.AddMessage(Id, customClass);
    return Ok(addEmailMessage.Result);
 }
```

Comment: Is there anything in the error log you can look at?

Comment: The WebApi simply returns a `'500 internal Server Error` and nothing else :(

Comment: Can you show an example of the problematic JSON that is being posted?  I'm wondering if there are unescaped quotes in there and that is causing the issue.  (In other words, it is not valid JSON)

Comment: Ok seems like it might be a encoding issue. Found this error in one of the logs I have `Unable to translate bytes [A3] at index 165 from specified code page to Unicode.`

Comment: Solved the issue had to set the encoding UTF8 inside my `WebClient`

Comment: Glad you were able to find the problem.